# How to work for video from url in videoplayback of qualcomm

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am working with **Videoplayback** sample of vuforia.I am using dat and xml for 3 images, and i also got image name while the camera is detecting any image of three imges. Now i want tIo play three different videos for those three images.I have started new **activty** for below android 4.0 devices and played video accordingly to image.

But my question is ***I am not able to play video from url for android above 4.0 devices which support video on texture.I need to play three different video for those three image after detection***.